# issue with Update query not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `id_product` = 9' at line 1

```
UPDATE `ps_product` SET `price` =  WHERE `id_product` = 9
```

Comment: Missing price ... UPDATE `ps_product` SET `price` = '12345689'  WHERE `id_product` = 9

Comment: @Quassnoi that explains 189K :)

Comment: @user1994082 On note of the question title: "Silly" shouldn't be used there. 
Even if it is a simple Problem just say "php SQL update query not working".

Comment: Agreed with @ThomasE. , now we can all see what "Silly" actually refers to ... given the Silly mistakes you made in your statement.

Comment: Easy rep, easy rep people

Comment: @Ayub Everyone makes mistakes so nothing silly about that. Also when I started posting here I put silly issue/problem, small issue/Problem into the titles myself until I saw that These words/phrases don't bring anything for helping ppl with helping me with my Problem. Thus they should be omitted (as they don't hold any info that could be helpful for those who would like to help one). but as asprin indicates back to Topic there.

Comment: @ThomasE. My point exactly ... adds no real value to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The value for price is missing in your sql:

```
UPDATE `ps_product` SET `price` =  WHERE `id_product` = 9
                                 ^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass empty value with in single or double quotes or any values

```
UPDATE `ps_product` SET `price` = ''  WHERE `id_product` = 9
```

Comment: I think the price is a nummeric filed so it should be initialized with zero not with blank.

Comment: if price is not there hard code it as zero. Remember if you have validation like !empty(0) will fail always " empty(0) is true "

Answer (score 1):

The Problem in your query is that you have "`price` =  WHERE ". As you didnt paste your whole code there I guess that the variable which holds the value with to which Price shall be set is empty. 
Thus you should control that variable and see why it is empty (in case the whole query is a string with no variables involved then you forgot the value to which Price shall be set).

If Price is meant to be empty you will have to set it to an empty value via either using ='', =null or =0 depending on what empty is represented by the field (and its type).